# Simple software for contacts, something between PIM and CRM with multi-language user interface

Tags: windows-7, information-management, crm

Please advice me some simple software for managing contacts and writing down notices from every call/meeting. I think something between PIM and CRM. For desktop with Windows 7 (not online, not cloud, not intranet portal...). And I would need multi-language feature - or directly Czech language user interface.

E.g. I have tried very nice EssentialPIM - but there is missing capability to add (to the contacts) separate notices (tagged by date) of every calls/meetings made with that contact.